# How do I link those tables?

Tags: sql, join

Ok so I have 3 sets of data like this:

Now I'd like to retrieve information about each pair

1. Product - Warehouse (I have 1000 records)
2. Warehouse - TransferNumber
3. Product - TransferNumber - Quantity

The final result I'm expecting is Product - Warehouse - Quantity.

It is bizarrely designed, but I want to pull all records from product warehouse to grab the quantity.

As I wanted to grab everything in ProductWarehouse, I tried to left outer join, it is supposed to return 1000 records but in reality it gives me 1500? Why it gives me more records?

Comment: The table design is not bizzare. Try to understand your data model and when a `Product-TransferNumber-Quantity` is inserted. Most likely it has an one-to-many relationship with product (has more than one record for a product). Some key details are missing in the question and that makes answering difficult.

Comment: You haven't showed us your schema, the approaches you've taken. Nor have you given us a clear problem statement,or sample data and expected results. Without some clarification, it's rather difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your outer join to an inner Join.
Outer joins will match on NULL values, so if you have entries in Warehouse that do not match Product an additional line will return where all the product info is NULL

(Best guess without more specific table information provided)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a schema that looks something like

```
create table Product
(
  product_id int not null ,
  ...
  primary key ( product_id ) ,
)
create table Warehouse
(
  warehouse_id int not null ,
  ...
  primary key ( warehouse_id ) ,
)
create table ProductWarehouse
(
  product_id   int not null ,
  warehouse_id int not null ,

  primary key ( product_id   , warehouse_id ) ,
  foreign key ( product_id   ) references Product(   product_id   ) ,
  foreign key ( warehouse_id ) references Warehouse( warehouse_id ) 

)
create table WarehouseTransferNumber
(
  transfer_number int not null ,
  warehouse_id    int not null ,
  ...
  primary key ( transfer_number ) ,
  foreign key ( warehouse_id ) references Warehouse( warehouse_id ) ,
)
create table ProductTransferNumber
(
  product_id      int not null ,
  transfer_number int not null ,
  quantity int not null ,
  ...
  primary key ( product_id , transfer_number ) ,
  foreign key ( product_id ) references Product( product_id ) ,
  foreign key ( transfer_number ) references WarehouseTransferNumber ( transfer_number ) ,
)
```

You ought to be able to say something like

```
select pw.product_id   ,
       pw.warehouse_id ,
       sum(ptn.quantity)
from ProductWarehouse        pw
join WarehouseTransferNumber wtn on wtn.warehouse_id = pw.warehouse_id
join ProductTransferNumber   ptn on ptn.product_id   = pw.product_id
group by pw.product_id ,
         pw.warehouse_id
```